# SQL Query is taking too long even not responding

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> desc airport
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 AIRPORT_ID                NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 CITY_ID                   NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 AIRPORT                        VARCHAR2(59)
 IATA_CODE                      VARCHAR2(3)

SQL> desc city
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CITY_ID                   NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 COUNTRY_ID                NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 CITY                           VARCHAR2(36)

SQL> desc country
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COUNTRY_ID                NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 COUNTRY                        VARCHAR2(36)
```

Here is the query:

```
select airport_id, airport, iata_code, city, country 
from airport a, city b, country c 
where a.city_id = b.city_id 
  and b.country_id = c.country_id 
  and b.city like '%tehran%' or iata_code like '%tehran%'
order by airport asc;
```

This query is not responding or talking minutes to respond whilst when I ran same query with one parameter like `and b.city like '%tehran%'` by removing `or iata_code like '%tehran%'` then its running fine and results in less than a second

why its not responding with two parameters e.g. `and b.city like '%tehran%' or iata_code like '%tehran%'`

Comment: Your query is taking forever because you didn't use parentheses for the OR condition. The way it is written, the query does a proper join of the three tables (on your conditions) and filters for city; OR it does a **Cartesian** join of all three tables, followed by filtering on IATA code (because the **join conditions** do not apply to the second member of the OR condition: no parentheses, and AND binds stronger than OR).

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  And learn to use meaningful table aliases!

Comment: Is the city never written as 'Tehran'?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson its dynamic and will be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want

```
select airport_id, airport, iata_code, city, country 
from airport a
join city b on a.city_id=b.city_id and (b.city like '%tehran%' or b.iata_code like '%tehran%')
join country c on b.country_id=c.country_id 
order by airport asc;
```

Note SQL standard JOIN syntax and the order of logical AND/OR operations fixed using brackets.